# PHP communicate between separate user sessions?

Tags: php, session, long-polling

I'm wondering if it's possible to interact between separate sessions in PHP? I'm asking this because I want to limit the amount of MySQL queries, as a lot of what goes on is dynamic and I want to find ways to make the interactions between users less painful for MySQL.

One example would be chatting. It would be so useful to have the chats shared some way between the users in their own sessions, instead of having to poll MySQL for new messages and etc.. If user A wrote a message and it was inserted into users B session, I could instantly pick it up in my long polling loop with no need to harass MySQL as often as possible.

Comment: "I could instantly pick it up in my long polling loop with no need to harass MySQL as often as possible" --- it's usually "cheaper" to "harass" mysql and have as light session as possible

Comment: Is it really? I was always under the impression that sessions work natively and don't put a lot of stress on the system. I've put all of the current user data, along with translations and etc into each session, and it's 40KB in size - I'm thinking that's not a lot?..

Comment: sessions have to serialize/deserialize every request, while for other data sources you may implement some caching strategy etc. 40kb is A LOT

Comment: OK.. So what would you suggest for translations? They take up most of the session, but where do I store it?.. And also regarding the question itself - is it possible to read/write into other sessions?

Comment: For chat, there are options available for streaming without any db involvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are realy worried about MySQL resources you could write the data in temp files on the server but i'm pretty sure this will end up in bad performance due to lots and lots of files needed to be opened, read, writen to etc.

A better solution would probably be to setup something using node.js. That way you can setup a realtime javascript chat. See: http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/ or http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/ for more info about this.